# Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, webassembly

Coding .net8 Blazor WASM with pre-rendering (not SSR) ... Does anyone know how to fix this error below?

**blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor:{"type":"webassembly","prerenderId":"da28410f78794bd18c6f30a6c37bec3a","key":{"locationHash":"4EE4D0430FFCBB1B4A06FB2BEE9F499B53DA581B:0","formattedComponentKey":""},"assembly":"Web.Client","typeName":"Web.Client.App","parameterDefinitions":"W10=","parameterValues":"W10="}**

Appears to be caused by this line of code `((MarkupString)item.DescriptionShortened(ShortDescLength)`

I'm rendering a list of item descriptions in a loop. And expected to see clean HTML output. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Without further details nobody can help you out. Share some part of the code that’s most likely causing the error

Comment: Create a new project and make a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my DescriptionShortened logic was truncating strings in the wrong place and producing invalid HTML.  For example, this call `((MarkupString)item.DescriptionShortened(ShortDescLength)` would produce this result...

> "you might have around `<b>`5g "

Clearly the `<b>` tag is not closing which caused Blazor to mark the page as invalid.  To Blazor's credit, there's some a threshold of bad HTML before it generates the error.  For some ppl this issue may appear intermittently if you only have a few "bad tags".

To fix the issue I just wrote an extension method to strip HTML tags from the output.  Maybe this will help if your requirement allows for removing HTML tags and just outputting the raw string value ...

```
public static class MarkupStringExtensions
{
    public static MarkupString StripTags(this MarkupString markupString)
    {
        var input = markupString.Value;

        var stripTags = Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

        return new MarkupString(stripTags);
    }
}
```

Please up vote if this is helpful for you, thanks!